# How could I avoid the pc to pick the same number?

Tags: arrays, c, random, flags

If I have an array like this

```
int numbers[10] = {1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7,8,8};
```

And I want to pick one randomly

```
i = numbers[rand()% 10];
```

How could I avoid the pc to pick the same number more than twice for this example. Because like you can see in the array the same number is repeated 2 times. So I would like, for example, the number 8 to be choose just twice and same for the other numbers.

I know that I could do something like mark an element as "deleted", e.g., by setting it to 0, then if the number chosen has been deleted, you choose again. But I don't know how to do it properly, so If anyone here can help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: Break it down into two parts: 1) generate the random number for index,  2) check the value at that index, if that's 0, go to step 1, otherwise, take that value, and use that index to set the value to 0. then go to step 1.

Comment: 1. Fill your array with allowed values; num_entries=number of elements. 2. Select an index from 0..<used-entries-1>. 3. Move last element to the just taken index position 4. used_entries--

Comment: so you suggest me to fill the array with a for loop instead of declare the set of number in the array definition?

Comment: Order/permute randomly, and pick the first few members? (or use reservoir sampling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the random number so it's equal to the yet unused number of elements and move unused elements to the front of the array.

```
#define SZ 10

int numbers[SZ] = {1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7,8,8};

for (int i = 0; i < SZ; ++i)
{
    // Generate the random number in the range [0 .. UNUSED-ELEMENTS]
    // First  loop in range [0..9]
    // Second loop in range [0..8]
    // and so on
    int r = rand() % (SZ-i);

    int d = numbers[r];
    printf("%d ", d);

    // Overwrite the used element with an unused element, i.e. last unused,
    // so that unused elements are always at the lowest array index
    numbers[r] = numbers[SZ-i-1];
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: thanks! I can't vote yet 'cause I don't have enough reputation, but I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Implemented with an array + "swap and pop":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static int pick_number(int *numbers, int max)
{
    int index = rand() % max;
    int result = numbers[index];
    
    // Swap
    numbers[index] = numbers[max-1];

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int numbers[10] = {1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7,8,8};
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        printf("got: %d\n", pick_number(numbers, i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```